# Could not resolve placeholder 'server.port' in value "${server.port}"

Tags: java, spring, jhipster

After upgrading a jHipster project from version 4.14.5 to the version 5.8.1 I am getting this error when I try to run the application:

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
>   refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  Error
>   creating bean with name 'loggingConfiguration' defined  in file
>   [\config\LoggingConfiguration.class]:
>
> Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  Could not resolve placeholder
>   'server.port' in value "${server.port}"

Do you have any idea of what could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Please post your yml and your LoggingConfiguration.java class.

Answer (score 0):

Spring looks for placeholders specified inside the `@Value` annotation in various locations. Since you're probably running a Spring Boot application, you might want to check the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) for externalized configuration.

I'd bet you did have it specified as a command line argument, or inside the `application.properties` resource file.

Btw, the `.` (dot) is not a problem.

Comment: Yes, this is a Spring boot application. This happens in a LoggingConfiguration file, it is generated by jHipster, I didn't change anything there nor in the .yml file.

Comment: @SemirDeljić maybe you didn't, but jHipster did. Isn't the server port something you have to set manually?

Comment: @SemirDeljić my suggestion would be to regenerate the application.

Comment: the application is regenerated with the jHipster upgrade on a separate branch, that is how the upgrade process works. After that, I've merged it to the local branch.

Comment: @SemirDeljić mmmh, are you sure you haven't lost anything in the merge process?

Comment: I will go through the merge process one more time. I am not sure if I've lost something along the way.

Comment: @SemirDeljić I'd start by looking at this, indeed. Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved this simply by adding the **server.port** property to **application.properties**

**MultiplicationController.java**

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/multiplications")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9090")
final class MultiplicationController {

    private final MultiplicationService multiplicationService;

    private final int serverPort;

    @Autowired
    public MultiplicationController(final MultiplicationService multiplicationService,
            @Value("${server.port}") int serverPort) {
        this.multiplicationService = multiplicationService;
        this.serverPort = serverPort;
    }

    @GetMapping("/random")
    public Multiplication getRandomMultiplication() {
        log.info("Generating a random multiplication from server @ {}", serverPort);
        return multiplicationService.createRandomMultiplication();
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8080
```

Answer (score -2):

I was just having the same issue.
It actually worked when I replaced the "."s with "_" 
So my method :

```
@Value("${server_port")
Integer port;
```

and my properties.yml

```
server:
  port: 1234
server_port: 1234
```

Of course, the redundancy isn't ideal, but @Value seems to be unable to handle "."s.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but I don't think this is the right approach for the problem.